# ngCordova Plugins - Issue getting cordova.js included properly

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova

I've been trying everything for the past two days to solve this issue. I'm well and truly stumped. Perhaps someone with greater knowledge than I can shed some light on the issue:

Basically, I'm building an app in AngularJS with the purpose of building Android and iOS apps from it using Cordova. I should specify that I am using cordova-cli on Linux and ngCordova (wrapper around plugins). I am NOT using Ionic Framework.

My app works fine in Chrome. I followed the ngCordova installation guide perfectly: http://ngcordova.com/docs/install/

I used bower to install. Then included the following in the index.html of my Web App project (not the Cordova project):

```
<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
```

It didn't work. I thought maybe it's because the ng-cordova.js went into my bower components directory. So I changed that script tag to:

```
bower_components/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js
```

When I go to my cordova project directory and set up the platforms, plugins etc... and run:

```
cordova build android
```

followed by

```
cordova run android
```

The app runs on my device (Nexus 5). I use chrome://inspect to see what happens when I click the button which should be using the email composer plugin: I get a cordova not defined error.

I went into the controller and put this in

```
console.log($cordovaEmailComposer);
```

I can examine this in chrome://insepct and it has all the correct functions etc.. so ng-cordova.js is running fine (thats where the factory for the plugin is).

I'm 99% sure the issue is that somewhere along the line cordova.js is being lost. When I go into the cordova project in the ProjectName/www/index.html the  tag for cordova.js is commented out.

Same in the platforms/android/assets/www/index.html file.

I traced it back and the same is true in WebAppProject/dist/index.html file. It's commented out. So it seems that when I run grunt build cordova.js is being removed. I thought maybe it's because cordova.js wasn't in the WebAppProject so I brought it into the root directory (same locations as index.html) and it still happened.

Can anyone explain how to properly get this working? I'm totally at a loss. I've tried a million different ways of including cordova.js. I even manually uncommented it out in the cordovaproject/www/index.html. The app builds but crashs upon opening (white screen then dies) suggesting a missing script (despite cordova.js being n that directory too...).

Is this the grunt build process? Or am I totally setting up an ngCordova project incorrectly without realising... I would post some code but I'm 99% sure the issue is with cordova.js or the way the project is building upon either grunt build or cordova build.

Any help would be much appreciated. :)

Cheers,
D

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to include ngCordova before cordova.js and after angular.js.

```
<script src="/path/to/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/ng-cordova.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/cordova.js"></script>
```